# twitter bootstrap drop down z-index and transparency visibility issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, z-index

I'm having trouble with my twitter bootstrap dropdown menus getting hidden underneath items and also with its transparency.  Example: http://pictorious-web-qa.herokuapp.com

[image]

1. The menu z-index goes below the profile photo when the screen
   shrinks down to around 400px wide.  I checked the media query but
   couldn't find any z-index settings.

   See http://pictorious-web-qa.herokuapp.com/profiles/albert for an
   example.
2. I want to keep the translucency in the menu nav but want to up the
   solid opacity of the dropdown menu items.  I've set the opacity on
   the menu container directly but that didn't seem to change anything.
3. The menu also has a z-index problem with the vimeo video on the home
   page http://www.pictorious.com if you shrink the screen width down
   to where the nav bar menu overlaps the video.  I've also tried
   setting the z-index to no avail and not sure how to set the wmode in
   the vimeo default iframe embed technique

It's a standard twitter bootstrap nav:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="/">Pictorious!</a>
      <div class="btn-group pull-right" id="nav-login">
            <a class="btn"  href="/login">Sign-In</a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/challenges">Challenges</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>

                        <form class="navbar-search pull-left form-search" action="/search">
                            <input type="text" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search" name="keyword">
                        </form>
                    </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

The only thing that seems to change on the overlapping photo is the margins and padding on the smaller media queries.

Comment: Where is a code? Where are screenshots? Please, don't ask to debug a website for you.

Comment: code snippet added and screenshot added

Answer (score 3):

So the answer was that I needed to set position to relative in the default bootstrap carousel and that's why it was not affected by my z-index property.

```
position: relative; z-index:-1;
```

Comment: thanks a ton , there was no option of giving 1000 upvotes or else i could have done that :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can't find the z-index settings, you can always override them by writing another class or ID of the same name later in your CSS-- just make another z-index there. Try setting the z-index of the top element lower as well as setting that of the bottom element higher.

Comment: I've tried tweaking the z-index settings but it doesn't seem to make a difference..

Comment: I had a similar issue that turned out to caused by "overflow: hidden" on a parent div. The solution was easy for me since, after reviewing it, I determined that I didn't need the overflow: hidden anymore so I removed it. That fixed this issue.